# undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'; argument order does not fix issue

Tags: c++, linux

On Ubuntu Linux, I have been following the `gtest` instructions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513905/how-to-properly-setup-googletest-on-linux) to install `gtest` with manually copying the header files and libraries to `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib`, respectively.

I then tried to compile the following code (`test1.cpp`)

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
TEST(MathTest, TwoPlusTwoEqualsFour) {
    EXPECT_EQ(2 + 2, 4);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest( &argc, argv );
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

with the following command (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27091412/how-to-compile-a-gtest-cpp-file#27091541) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482445/undefined-reference-to-pthread-key-create))

```
g++ -Wall -g -pthread test1.cpp -lgtest_main  -lgtest -lpthread
```

just to see the following errors:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libgtest.so: undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libgtest.so: undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libgtest.so: undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libgtest.so: undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The generic answer was about the order of the arguments to `g++`. However, I think I have tried every combinatoric order of the arguments `-lpthread` (with and without the `l`), `-lgtest` and `-lgtest_main`. I always get the same errors.

I do not think the order is the problem. It must be something else. Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For linking the `gtest` library to your gtest, it seems one must use the static gtest libraries (for unknown reasons; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21116622/undefined-reference-to-pthread-key-create-linker-error)). So instead of using the command line like

```
g++ -Wall -g -pthread test1.cpp -lgtest_main  -lgtest -lpthread
```

one must use

```
g++ -Wall -g  -pthread test1.cpp    /usr/lib/libgtest.a
```

Here, the library is located in `/usr/lib`, but depending on how `gtest` was installed the file `libgtest.a` is located somethere else.